# Can we modifiy the filters inside modern search page

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, managed-metadata, modern-experience

I am working on sharepoint online communication site, the site contain 10 document libraries. and these document libraries share 5 managed metadata site columns link to them. now i can manually search the documents, and i got the results inside the modern search page. where inside the modern sharepoint search we have filters (unlike the classic search which use to have refiners)., as follow:-

[image]

so my question is, if i can add  our 5 managed metadata site columns as filters inside the modern search? so in this case i can filter the document libraries based on the managed metadata values?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not supported to customize the filters you see on the verticals of search.

Microsoft team mentioned that they’re ongoing on adding new filters and custom filters. Don't have an ETA yet but are experimenting with among others author refiners.

More information and update you can check the thread: [SharePoint Online Search Filters - Managed Metadata](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/SharePoint-Online-Search-Filters-Managed-Metadata/m-p/209259)